# Where to put a global custom directive in Angular 16 without an AppModule?

Tags: angular, angular16

In Angular 16, if you are using an application without an AppModule, where should you put a global custom directive that you imported in the AppModule declarations?

For example
I have a directive called hasRole that I used to add to the declarations array of the AppModule in Angular 15 to use it globally. However, I am not using an AppModule in Angular 16. Where should I declare this directive to use it globally?

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate it into a `standalone` directive and directly import it into each component where it's needed.

You can learn more about `standalone` components, directives, and pipes in this Angular guide:
https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

Comment: Yes, but I want to use it in all the components, so is there a way to declare it globally?